# Using 'in' keyword for passing in readonly classes in C# 7.2

Tags: c#, .net, vector

I'm not understanding why the keyword `in` works here but not in a different scenario.

In this case, this works as expected. Vector2D is a class.

```
/// <summary>
/// Copy constructor.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="vector2D">The Vector2D object to copy.</param>
public Vector2D(in Vector2D vector2D)
{
    vector2D = new Vector2D(5.2f, 1.5f);  // fails (readonly)

    m_x = vector2D.m_x;
    m_y = vector2D.m_y;
}
```

However, I tried this case:

```
/// <summary>
/// Copy constructor.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="vector2D">The Vector2D object to copy.</param>
public Vector2D(in Vector2D vector2D)
{
    vector2D.m_x++; (this increments, no longer readonly??)

    m_x = vector2D.m_x;
    m_y = vector2D.m_y;
}
```

Initially, the second example feels like a bug in comparison to the first example. So, I'm not understanding why `in` worked in the first example, but the second the `readonly` status no longer applies in the second example.

1. Why is this happening?
2. What's the alternative to keep the second example `readonly`?

Update:
When I change Vector2D from `class` to `struct`, #2 works as I expect with `readonly`. When I change it to `class`, it changes.

Example with Vector2D as a struct type:

```
/// <summary>
/// Copy constructor.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="vector2D">The Vector2D object to copy.</param>
public Vector2D(in Vector2D vector2D)
{
    vector2D.m_x++; (fails, readonly)

    m_x = vector2D.m_x;
    m_y = vector2D.m_y;
}
```

When I change Vector2D to class, `vector2D.m_x++` is valid. C# is getting more confusing with each update.

I mean, sure, I'll be changing Vector2D to `struct` anyway for performance benefits, but for classes I'm confused why it differs here.

Comment: _"b) What's the alternative to keep the second example readonly?"_ Use immutable types

Comment: `vector2D` is just a name. `in` protects you from changing the name -- not its contents.

Comment: Immutable vectors have a huge performance hit for graphics-intense applications and are not suitable in this case, although immutable objects are suitable in other cases. Too much memory allocation during runtime with thousands of existing vectors.

Comment: `in` only makes the *variable* readonly. When the variable contains a `struct` it basically contains the entire struct, and thus by proxy the struct (in this call) also becomes readonly. If it contains a reference type all it contains is a reference. Again, you're only making the *variable* readonly, thus you cannot switch to a new reference, but if the object it refers to is mutable there is no stopping you from mutating that object.

Comment: Note that using `in` with reference types might convey *meaning*, but it doesn't do **anything** for performance. `in` basically means you'll be passing a pointer to the variable with the reference, this has the same size as the reference to begin with. The difference comes with structs where you'll be passing a pointer to the struct, instead of the whole struct, which *has* a size difference.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you are trying to *overwrite the variable*.

```
vector2D = new Vector2D(5.2f, 1.5f);  // fails (readonly)
```

In the second case, you are updating a *read-write* field of the variable, you are not changing the variable itself.

```
// this increments, we are not changing the variable,
// we are changing a field of the variable.
vector2D.m_x++;
```

### Similar Example

This is quite similar to making a read-only property that returns an object.

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private List<string> list = new List<string>();

    // Read-only property
    public List<string> List { get { return list } }
}
```

You cannot *set* the property:

```
var x = new SomeClass();

// Dosen't compile
x.List = new List<string>();
```

But since the property returns a *writeable* object, you can modify it:

```
var x = new SomeClass();

// This works
x.List.Add("Hello");
```

### Struct Type

In the 3rd case, you are back to modifying the *actual variable* because you have changed it to be a struct, which is a *value type*. On the other hand, a class is a *reference type*. The value of the reference type variable is a *pointer* to the memory location of the data. When using a value type, you are actually passing the data *in* the variable.

> C# is getting more confusing with each update.

Not sure what you mean by this. Value types and reference types are not exclusive to C# and they have always worked the same since the very beginning of .NET.

Comment: That was a really great explanation on the differences between structs and classes and demystified structs comming from C# and never using them. So is `x.List.Add("Hello")` just an arbitrary refrence that C# makes  To The Object class?

Comment: When you declare a type as a `class`, you are declaring it as a *reference type*. That means when you make a variable of that type, the variable is only a pointer to the memory location of the instance. The variable is only a way to access the value, but it does not *contain* the value like a value type does. In the example above, the property is read-only. The variable that it returns (a reference) is not read-only.